# How to write response from api to formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

How to write response from api to formik?
I have an api by which I receive data, this data is completely consistent with my form, how can I immediately write the entire response so as not to make many setFieldValue lines?

```
const form = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
          name: "",
          login: "",
          about: {
            age: "",
            rank: {
              silver: true,
              gold: false,
              global: false
            }
          }
        }
      }); // My initial form

  const {
    values,
    handleChange,
    setFieldValue,
  } = form;

useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(projectData)) {
      Object?.keys(projectData)?.map((item: any, idx: number) => {
        const key: any = Object.keys(item).at(-1);
        setFieldValue(key, item[key]);
      });
    }
  }, [projectData]); // Set response api
```

Comment: You can use setValues to do in one go. https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setvalues-fields-reactsetstateaction-field-string-any--shouldvalidate-boolean--void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape of the data you're receiving from the API matches the structure of your form, you can set the entire state at once using the `setValues` method.

Make sure the data structure from your API response (`projectData`) matches the structure of your `initialValues`.

Use the `setValues` method to update all the values at once.

```
const form = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    name: "",
    login: "",
    about: {
      age: "",
      rank: {
        silver: true,
        gold: false,
        global: false
      }
    }
  }
});

const { setValues } = form;

useEffect(() => {
  if (projectData) {
    setValues(projectData);
  }
}, [projectData]); // Set response from API
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `enableReinitialize` to allow Formik to [update](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean) the values upon changes.

```js
const form = useFormik({
    initialValues: ...,
    enableReinitialize: true //<-- Here
});
```

You can, also, directly set the values in a single go in your `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (projectData && .../*Other conditions*/) {
        form.setValues(projectData)
    }
}, [projectData])
```